# Function whose graph is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f:(a, b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be some continuous function on an open interval $(a, b)$ s.t.
$\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to b}f(x)=\infty$. I want to determine whether the graph of $f$ is closed, i.e. whether the set
$$
G(f)=\left\{(x, f(x)) \mid x\in (a, b)\right\}
$$
is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Using the fact that a closed set contains all its limit points I was thinking about using this to get a contradiction,
but since (informal) $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \ (x, f(x)) = (0, \infty)$
I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: Take a converging sequence of $G(f)$ and use the continuity of $f$ to show the limit is in $G(f)$.

Comment: @blamethelag If you made that into an answer I would upvote it; I prefer your idea over mine.

Comment: About showing the complement is open for point $(a,z)$ denote $m$ so that for all $a<x\leq m$ you have $f(x) > z+1$ then $B((a, z), \min(1,(m-a)/2))$ is in complement.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence of $G(f)$ with limit $z \in \mathbb R^2$. Set $z_n = (x_n,f(x_n))$ and $z = (x,y)$. We show that $x \in (a,b)$ and $y = f(x)$, which is enough to conclude that $z \in G(f)$. We know that by definition of the topology on $\mathbb R^2$ (or by the definition of the product topology)
$$
x_n \rightarrow x~~and~~f(x_n) \rightarrow y.
$$
Then $x \in \overline{(a,b)}$, but necessarily $x \notin \{a,b \}$. Indeed, if for instance $x = a$, using the limit of $f$ at $a$ we would have
$$
f(x_n) \rightarrow \infty
$$
and by the unicity of the limit $\infty = y \in \mathbb R$ which is absurd. So $x \in (a,b)$ and since $f$ is continuous over $(a,b)$,
$$
y = \lim f(x_n) = f(x).
$$

Answer (score 0):

A subset is closed if its complement is open. A subset is open if every point within that subset is contained in an open ball within that subset. Can you take it from here?

Comment: hm this makes me think that the set is indeed closed, looking at the graph. Could you maybe tell me whether my intuition is right and then I try to formalise it?

Comment: I could; you could also try to formalise it and see how far you get ;) Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: I'm very new to this topic, hence I'm a bit stuck. My idea is that for most points finding such an open ball is very easy, the only interesting once are those at the line $x=a$ and $x=b$. But also for them one can find such a ball by choosing its radius as the minimum distance to the graph of $(a, z)$ and $(a, z+1)$ with $(a, z)$ being the point we want to find the open ball for. But in general I have no idea how to formalise this.

Comment: @Rhi Formalizing this may indeed be difficult, depending on the tools you have available to you. If you are very new to this topic, perhaps the approach suggested in the comment by blamethelag will suit you better.

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma 1:** For every bounded set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, there exists $c,d \in (a,b)$ such that $f^{-1}(A) \subset [c,d]$.

*Proof:* It is obvious from the limits assumption.

**Lemma 2:** Let $(x_n,y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of elements of the graph of $f$ that converges in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then there exists $c,d \in (a,b)$ such that for every $n$, $x_n \in [c,d]$.

*Proof:* A converging sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is bounded, so the set $\{y_n \ \vert \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded, so we can apply Lemma 1 to get that there are $c,d$ such that $\{x_n \ \vert \ n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset f^{-1}(\{y_n \ \vert \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}) \subset [c,d]$.

*Proof of the closedness of the graph:* Let $(x_n,y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of elements of the graph of $f$ that converges, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, to $(x,y)$. One has to show that $(x,y)$ is in the graph of $f$. According to Lemma 2, $x \in [c,d] \subset (a,b)$, so, by continuity of $f$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(x)$, so $(x,y)$ is in the graph of $f$.